# Proper 3 Tier architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, web, three-tier

I know that three tier contain `PL` , `BL` and `DL`.
 Working on one, in that application we are

> "passing values as parameter from PL into BL and after calculation into DL which perform DB operations."

**Is this the right way to implement 3 Tier?**

or the one described here in **[CODEPROJECT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11128/3-tier-architecture-in-C)**

**Edit**
I know There is no "one fits all" layer model. But i want to know which is better

1. Passing parameters?
2. Setting get set values of table field?(As in above `codeplex` example)

Comment: @syed mohsin what you have asked in your question I think it is the better way. Methods Add, Update, Delete should be there in BL and in DL there should be methods like executeNoneQuery or executeScalar that performs database operation.

Comment: There is no "one fits all" layer model. It entirely depends on the project and scope, but [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is an often used strategy in complex systems. The classic 3-Tier model is often used as an example in teaching.

Comment: There is no "right way" you need to choose the better solution to your specific need.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Above there are 2 ways to implement 3 Tier. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

The method mentioned by you is for simple scenario. The Architecture(Tiers) of application can be differ from one user to another user or Organisation. But the process mentioned by you is the basic one.

http://alitarhini.wordpress.com/2011/01/22/concepts-of-three-tier-architecture/